# Spaces in keys in new Python 2.7-based Google App Engine?

Tags: google-app-engine

I'm trying to upgrade my GAE app from being based on Python 2.5 to Python 2.7. My app permits users to choose names that contain spaces for entities such as folders but the app converts space to %20 before forming a key for the data store. Problems I'm having in upgrading might be explainable if GAE now converts a %20 in a proposed key to a space, which it didn't do in the Python 2.5 version of GAE.

Can anyone tell me whether space or %20 has any special status in GAE data store keys, and whether there has been a change in this policy in going from Python 2.5 to 2.7? More generally, is there documentation somewhere that I've missed that states whether there are restrictions on characters that are legal in keys?

If there has been such a change, I'm in a tricky position because the existing user database has keys that contain %20.

Comment: It does appear that I can in fact use a key containing %20 and use the key later in that form. But I'm still curious as to whether there are any restrictions on character codes in key strings.

Comment: I think I finally figured out what the real problem was, and this might be of general interest. When based on Python 2.5 the Python code contained "from django.utils import simplejson as json", whereas the new code based on Python 2.7 has "import json". Apparently in the old scheme $.ajax PUT automatically converted space to %20, but not in the new scheme, and I need to do the conversion myself before doing the PUT.